# Ansible: Add Unix group to user only if the group exists

Tags: unix, ansible

I'm using Ansible to add a user to a variety of servers.  Some of the servers have different UNIX groups defined. I'd like to find a way for Ansible to check for the existence of a group that I specify, and if that group exists, add it to a User's secondary groups list (but ignore the statement it if the group does not exist).

Any thoughts on how I might do this with Ansible?

Here is my starting point.

**Command**

```
ansible-playbook -i 'localhost,' -c local ansible_user.yml
```

**ansible_user.yml**

```
---

- hosts: all
  user: root
  become: yes
  vars:
    password: "!"
    user: testa
  tasks:
    - name: add user
      user: name="{{user}}"
            state=present
            password="{{password}}"
            shell=/bin/bash
            append=yes
            comment="test User"
```

**Updated:** based on the solution suggested by @udondan, I was able to get this working with the following additional tasks.

```
    - name: Check if user exists
      shell: /usr/bin/getent group | awk -F":" '{print $1}'
      register: etc_groups

    - name: Add secondary Groups to user
      user: name="{{user}}" groups="{{item}}" append=yes
      when: '"{{item}}" in etc_groups.stdout_lines'
      with_items: 
          - sudo
          - wheel
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you have anything to identify those different host types?

If not, you first need to check which groups exist on that host. You can do this with the command `getent group | cut -d: -f1` which will output one group per line.

You can use this as separate task like so:

```
- shell: getent group | cut -d: -f1
  register: unix_groups
```

The registered result then can be used later when you want to add the user group

```
- user: ...
  when: "'some_group' in unix_groups.stdout_lines"
```

Comment: The groups command on >=7.0 Red Hat and friends does not print all the groups in /etc/groups. It only prints the groups the current user is in.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, the "groups ..." command prints only the groups the current user belongs to

Comment: You need to register a different variable in this example because "groups" is an Ansible reserved variable:- https://github.com/lorin/ansible-quickref

Comment: `getent group` would be the standard command to get the groups on the system. (`getent group | cut -d: -f1` for just the group names)

Comment: thanks \o/
I'm using it with ` | intersection ` and it is working like a charm
```yml
- shell: "getent group | cut -d: -f1"
  register: unix_groups
- ansible.builtin.user:
    groups: "{{ user['groups'] | default([]) | intersect(unix_groups.stdout_lines) }}"
```

Comment: @gilesw unix_groups is already a different variable from groups

Comment: `shell:` (or `command:`) is an inferior method to the `getent:` module.  The shell and command modules are highly dependent on the type of unix/linux, the shell being run, and environment variables.  The ansible.builtin.getent module is designed to work across a variety of operating systems.

Answer (score 27):

The [getent](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/getent_module.html#getent-module) module can be used to read /etc/group

```
- name: Determine available groups
  getent:
    database: group

- name: Add additional groups to user
  user: name="{{user}}" groups="{{item}}" append=yes
  when: item in ansible_facts.getent_group
  with_items: 
      - sudo
      - wheel
```

Comment: This doesn't work always return: 'ansible_facts' is undefined even if I gather facts

Comment: `ansible_facts.getent_group` will not exist unless you have run the getent module with `database: group`.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I'm dealing with this in my playbooks. The idea is simple - to take a list of existing groups and find an intersection between groups a user wants to be member of and groups that exist:

```
- name: Get Existing Groups
  getent:
    database: group

- name: Configure Users
  user:
    name: username
    groups: "{{ ['wheel', 'docker', 'video'] | intersect(ansible_facts['getent_group'] | list) }}"
```

The `getent` module outputs the 'getent_group' Ansible fact containing all existing groups with their details. By piping it to  `| list` filter I get plain list of group names. The `intersect` filter finds what's common between two lists.

One of the advantages of this solution is that I don't have to use *append* parameter of the `user` module. This way user may be correctly removed from groups that I don't want it to be member of anymore.

Answer (score -1):

I had the similar requirement, then I did the followings,

> ansible [core 2.12.2]

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  tasks:
     - ansible.builtin.user:
         name: test1
         password: "&&**%%^^"
         uid: 1234
         shell: /bin/bash

     - ansible.builtin.shell:
         "cat /etc/group| grep -o sysadmin"
       register: output

#you can omit the debug part
     - debug:
         var: output

     - name: assign user the group
       ansible.builtin.shell:
          "usermod -G sysadmin test1"
       when: "'sysadmin' in output.stdout_lines"
```

Update: Thanks for the suggestion @Jeter-work

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks: 
     - name: Get all groups
       ansible.builtin.getent:
         database: group
         split: ':'
     - debug:
         var: ansible_facts.getent_group
```

Comment: `ansible.builtin.shell:` is inferior to `ansible.builtin.getent:`  And even if you were going to use shell, better to use `getent`.  See the existing answer which shows the use of the `getent:` module.